# How do I prevent Entity Framework Core 7 from adding a foreign key field to a certain class referring to that same class, when creating a migration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Thanks for reading this. I am kind of new to Entity Framework Core, and I am trying to use the code first principle to create migrations that should create my database.

But I stumble upon some unexpected behaviour, at least in my view. Perhaps someone is kind enough to help me, I might be doing something wrong.

I created a sample project with the following properties:

1. VS2022 Community (64 bit) version 17.6.5
2. C# (.NET 6.0)
3. Entity Framework Core 7.0.10 (I use `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design`, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` packages)

The target database is SQL Server.

I created a class `SampleEntity` as follows:

```c#
namespace Model.SampleEntitySet
{
    public class SampleEntity : SampleEntities
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

SampleEntities is defined as follows:

```c#
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Model.SampleEntitySet;

namespace Model
{
    public class SampleEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<SampleEntity> SampleEntitySet { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Something");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<SampleEntity>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.Id); // Configure primary key
            });
        }
    }
}
```

When I create the migration I use the command:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --context SampleEntities
```

And then the following Migration is created:

```c#
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

#nullable disable

namespace Model.Migrations
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public partial class InitialCreate : Migration
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "SampleEntitySet",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
                    Description = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                    SampleEntityId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_SampleEntitySet", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_SampleEntitySet_SampleEntitySet_SampleEntityId",
                        column: x => x.SampleEntityId,
                        principalTable: "SampleEntitySet",
                        principalColumn: "Id");
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_SampleEntitySet_SampleEntityId",
                table: "SampleEntitySet",
                column: "SampleEntityId");
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "SampleEntitySet");
        }
    }
}
```

The snapshot contains:

```c#
// <auto-generated />
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;

#nullable disable

namespace Model.Migrations
{
    [DbContext(typeof(SampleEntities))]
    partial class SampleEntitiesModelSnapshot : ModelSnapshot
    {
        protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
            modelBuilder
                .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "7.0.10")
                .HasAnnotation("Relational:MaxIdentifierLength", 128);

            SqlServerModelBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumns(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity("Model.SampleEntitySet.SampleEntity", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<Guid>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                        .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier");

                    b.Property<string>("Description")
                        .IsRequired()
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<Guid?>("SampleEntityId")
                        .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.HasIndex("SampleEntityId");

                    b.ToTable("SampleEntitySet");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("Model.SampleEntitySet.SampleEntity", b =>
                {
                    b.HasOne("Model.SampleEntitySet.SampleEntity", null)
                        .WithMany("SampleEntitySet")
                        .HasForeignKey("SampleEntityId");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("Model.SampleEntitySet.SampleEntity", b =>
                {
                    b.Navigation("SampleEntitySet");
                });
#pragma warning restore 612, 618
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that SampleEntityId as entity is created as nullable Guid and a foreign key FK_SampleEntitySet_SampleEntitySet_SampleEntityId.

I searched the internet to understand why this happens, but so far I didn't find the solution.
I know that I can manually remove the extra field and the foreign key with its index. But I don't want to have them created at all. It doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is your entity class (SampleEntity) inheriting your class that inherits
DbContext? I believe to fix your issue you just need to change `public class SampleEntity : SampleEntities` to just `public class SampleEntity`.

Take a look at this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/

Comment: This indeed solved my issue. Since I am beginner I use a lot of internet searching and that's how I got to derive from SampleEntities. Thanks a lot for helping!